# Firefox console response raw by default

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

Does anybody know how to set the Raw toggle on Firefox console response to Raw by default?

I don't know when this button was added, but now I need to press it every run to actually see the response, otherwise, it gives blank response, very annoying.

[image]

Comment: What kind of console response, and why does it not show as is?

Comment: Post response, and I wish I knew why it doesn't show as is, like it used to for years.

Comment: So you mean the Network tab, request properties. There are several Raw toggles there. Two on the Headers tab (one for request, one for response), one on the Request tab and one on the Response tab.

Comment: @GSerg I edited my question and added a photo. With Raw not toggled and toggled. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As of Firefox 109, there is no way to set the raw display of the response by default.

There is a long-standing [feature request for persisting the option](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1555647), though, which covers this use case.